# What is the English word for this type of run/race?

Tags: terminology

Imagine a place with no defined path/trail to run for example in a jungle. Only the source and destination are given. The runners/participants should reach the destination from the source. Time is not a metric to select the winner, instead there are some pre-defined intermediary points in the jungle where the participant should compulsorily visit and get a stamp or some mark on a piece of the paper as a proof that he visited it.

The participant who visits all the pre-defined points in the jungle and reaches the destination with all the proofs only wins! The participants are only told about the count of pre-defined intermediary points so that they know they have enough to reach the destination.

Is there a word or expression for this type of run/race?

Comment: This sounds like *orienteering,* although **not knowing where the checkpoints actually are** would make it quite difficult, and may mean that *orienteering* is not the name. But we have the Outdoors site with specialists who are likely to know. This question is more on-topic there.

Comment: This is orienteering but some of the points, don't make sense. How on earth would you know where to visit if your not told where any of the points are? Orienteering races are timed, first one to reach all the points and return.

Comment: this could also be adventure racing, though this typically involves a predetermined route and again, is timed.

Answer (score 9):

***Orienteering*** - A competitive sport in which runners have to find their way across rough country with the aid of a map and compass. Also (occas.) with competitors using skis, riding on horseback, etc. (OED)

1948   Amer. Ski Ann. 1949 146/1   Senior Scouts representing 15 Boy Scout Councils from New York and New Jersey met at Snow Ridge Ski Center last winter to compete in the first official Ski Orienteering race to be held in America.

1954   Time 1 Nov. 58   Known officially as ‘orienteering’, the sport dates back to 1918 when the first Swedish club was formed to hold formal competitions.

1973   Whole Earth Catal. 23/1   Within recent years, Orienteering as a sport, in the form of ‘Orienteering Races’ has swept Europe... Orienteering events have become regular features in many athletic and outdoor clubs.

1999   Scouting Mag. Nov. 40/1 (advt.)    The National Trust Campsites have special facilities for Youth Groups including the use of Pioneering poles, ropes & orienteering equipment.

Comment: I wondered about '*hashing*' - but I think that is slightly different https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_House_Harriers

Answer (score 2):

It's a combination, Scouting, Orienteering and Reconoiter.

Scouting, because you have to find evidence of previous recent passage to find stamp stations.

Orienteering, so you know which direction you are going and where on the map you are and have been and where you haven't yet been.

Reconoiter, in general because you are exploring with a mission in mind looking for likely places a stamp station might be and ways in and out of various hiding spots and paths of ingress and egress into those spots.